# Display 2 Databound fields in 1 CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a webapp where I can generate barcodes with user input that's taken from a textbox and a database. In the CheckBoxList, It takes a databound value from the database to be displayed onto the checkboxlist.

```
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text = sdr["BarCodeGroupName"].ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarCodeGroupName", BarCodeInit);
                BatchCode.Items.Add(item);

            }
        }
```

It will display the Group Names which is basically initials that relate to a longer description.

```
    []AA
    []BB
    []CC
```

What I want to do is add the other column from the database that is the actual description of the Group Name to look like:

```
    []AA Desc of Group1
    []BB Desc of Group2
    []CC Desc of Group3
```

If I add the information to my list, my barcodes will generate with the description instead of just the group name, is there are way to retrieve the information from my database and have it display only along with the group names and not become part of what is being generated. I don't want to simply label it in the .ASPX because newer groupnames will be added to the databse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to assign the Text as BarCodeGroupName + BarCodeGroupDesc and the item Value as just BarcodeGroupName

```
 using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
 {
     while (sdr.Read())
     {
         ListItem item = new ListItem();
         item.Text = sdr["BarCodeGroupName"].ToString() + " " + sdr["BarCodeGroupDesc"].ToString();
         item.Value = sdr["BarCodeGroupName"].ToString();
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarCodeGroupName", BarCodeInit);
         BatchCode.Items.Add(item);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed thank you. I knew I should have added the item Value, but I can't believe I never thought to just add the description with +. Thanks again.